# Cannot publish to dead letter topic on transaction failed

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

In my application, I set up Kafka as following.

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
                                                                                                 ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> consumerFactory,
                                                                                                 KafkaTransactionManager<?, ?> kafkaTransactionManager,
                                                                                                 KafkaTemplate<Object, Object> template) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        configurer.configure(factory, consumerFactory);
        
        // Send all failed message from topic XYZ to another dead-letter topic with .DLT suffix (i.e. XYZ.DLT)
        factory.getContainerProperties().setTransactionManager(kafkaTransactionManager);
        factory.setAfterRollbackProcessor(new DefaultAfterRollbackProcessor<>(new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(template), new FixedBackOff(50, 1)));

        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RecordMessageConverter converter() {
      return new StringJsonMessageConverter();
    }
}
```

Below is what I have in `application.yml`

```
spring:
  kafka:
    admin:
      fail-fast: true
    consumer:
      bootstrap-servers: 127.0.0.1:9092
      group-id: wfo
      enable-auto-commit: false
      auto-offset-reset: latest
      key-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer2
      value-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer2
      properties:
        spring.deserializer.key.delegate.class: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
        spring.deserializer.value.delegate.class: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
        isolation.level: read_committed
    producer:
      bootstrap-servers: 127.0.0.1:9092
      transaction-id-prefix: tx.
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
```

To test listeners on transaction failure, I created the following class.

```
@Service
public class EventListener {
    @KafkaListener(topics="test_topic")
    public void listen(TestEvent event) {
        System.out.println("RECEIVED EVENT: " + event.getPayload());

        if (event.getPayload().contains("fail"))
            throw new RuntimeException("TEST TRANSACTION FAILED");
    }
}
```

When I publish a `TestEvent`, I can see the payload printed on the console. When I include the word `fail` in my payload, a `RuntimeException` is thrown and I see a `Transaction rolled back` error message on the console.

However, after retry failed for about a minute, I saw the following exception on the console.

```
2020-06-20 17:07:46,326 ERROR [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.kafka.support.LoggingProducerListener   : Exception thrown when sending a message with key='null' and payload='{"customerCode":"DVTPRDFT411","payload":"MSGfail 90"}' to topic test_topic.DLT and partition 2:
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic test_topic.DLT not present in metadata after 60000 ms.
2020-06-20 17:07:46,327 ERROR [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.kafka.listener.DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer   : Dead-letter publication failed for: ProducerRecord(topic=test_topic.DLT, partition=2, headers=RecordHeaders(headers = [RecordHeader(key = __TypeId__, value = [99, 111, 109, 46, 102, 116, 46, 100, 101, 109, 111, 46, 100, 116, 111, 46, 100, 101, 98, 117, 103, 46, 75, 97, 102, 107, 97, 69, 118, 101, 110, 116, 82, 101, 113, 117, 101, 115, 116, 36, 71, 101, 110, 101, 114, 105, 99, 69, 118, 101, 110, 116]), RecordHeader(key = kafka_dlt-original-topic, value = [116, 101, 115, 116, 95, 116, 111, 112, 105, 99]), RecordHeader(key = kafka_dlt-original-partition, value = [0, 0, 0, 2]), RecordHeader(key = kafka_dlt-original-offset, value = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), RecordHeader(key = kafka_dlt-original-timestamp, value = [0, 0, 1, 114, -48, -29, -90, 47]), RecordHeader(key = kafka_dlt-original-timestamp-type, value = [67, 114, 101, 97, 116, 101, 84, 105, 109, 101]), RecordHeader(key = kafka_dlt-exception-fqcn, value = [111, 114, 103, 46, 115, 112, 114, 105, 110, 103, 102, 114, 97, 109, 101, 119, 111, 114, 107, 46, 107, 97, 102, 107, 97, 46, 108, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 46, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 69, 120, 101, 99, 117, 116, 105, 111, 110, 70, 97, 105, 108, 101, 100, 69, 120, 99, 101, 112, 116, 105, 111, 110]), RecordHeader(key = kafka_dlt-exception-message, value = [76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 32, 109, 101, 116, 104, 111, 100, 32, 39, 112, 117, 98, 108, 105, 99, 32, 118, 111, 105, 100, 32, 99, 111, 109, 46, 102, 116, 46, 100, 101, 109, 111, 46, 115, 101, 114, 118, 105, 99, 101, 46, 69, 118, 101, 110, 116, 76, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 101, 114, 46, 108, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 40, 99, 111, 109, 46, 102, 116, 46, 101, 118, 101, 110, 116, 46, 109, 97, 110, 97, 103, 101, 109, 101, 110, 116, 46, 100, 101, 102, 105, 110, 105, 116, 105, 111, 110, 46, 84, 101, 115, 116, 69, 118, 101, 110, 116, 41, 39, 32, 116, 104, 114, 101, 119, 32, 101, 120, 99, 101, 112, 116, 105, 111, 110, 59, 32, 110, 101, 115, 116, 101, 100, 32, 101, 120, 99, 101, 112, 116, 105, 111, 110, 32, 105, 115, 32, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 82, 117, 110, 116, 105, 109, 101, 69, 120, 99, 101, 112, 116, 105, 111, 110, 58, 32, 84, 69, 83, 84, 32, 84, 82, 65, 78, 83, 65, 67, 84, 73, 79, 78, 32, 70, 65, 73, 76, 69, 68, 59, 32, 110, 101, 115, 116, 101, 100, 32, 101, 120, 99, 101, 112, 116, 105, 111, 110, 32, 105, 115, 32, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 82, 117, 110, 116, 105, 109, 101, 69, 120, 99, 101, 112, 116, 105, 111, 110, 58, 32, 84, 69, 83, 84, 32, 84, 82, 65, 78, 83, 65, 67, 84, 73, 79, 78, 32, 70, 65, 73, 76, 69, 68]), RecordHeader(key = kafka_dlt-exception-stacktrace, value = [111, 100]), RecordHeader(key = b3, value = [100, 57, 51, 100, 56, 97, 98, 57, 55, 54, 97, 100, 54, 102, 49, 100, 45, 100, 57, 51, 100, 56, 97, 98, 57, 55, 54, 97, 100, 54, 102, 49, 100, 45, 49])], isReadOnly = false), key=null, value={"customerCode":"DVTPRDFT411","payload":"MSGfail 90"}, timestamp=null)
org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Send failed; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic test_topic.DLT not present in metadata after 60000 ms.
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.doSend(KafkaTemplate.java:570)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.send(KafkaTemplate.java:385)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.publish(DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.java:278)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.lambda$accept$3(DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.java:209)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.executeInTransaction(KafkaTemplate.java:463)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.accept(DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.java:208)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.accept(DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.java:54)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.FailedRecordTracker.skip(FailedRecordTracker.java:106)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekUtils.lambda$doSeeks$2(SeekUtils.java:84)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekUtils.doSeeks(SeekUtils.java:81)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.DefaultAfterRollbackProcessor.process(DefaultAfterRollbackProcessor.java:102)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.recordAfterRollback(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1700)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListenerInTx(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1662)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1614)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1348)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1064)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:972)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

For some reasons, the code couldn't publish events to the DLT topic. I tried to edit broker configurations to include `listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092` but it didn't help.

I'd be very grateful if you could point me in some direction to resolve this issue.

**UPDATE:

I do see the DLT topic when I execute the `kafka-topics --list --zookeeper localhost:2181` command.

[image]

By the way, this might be a bug from the latest Spring Kafka version. I downgraded to Kafka v2.4.1 and Spring Boot v2.2.7 and it's working fine. I reported the bug here.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1516

If there's some new configurations to be done in Kafka v2.5.0 to make this work, please let me know.

Comment: Are you able to see the topic using `kafka-topics`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic test_topic.DLT not present in metadata after 60000 ms.

From the error, it seems that you do not have the `test_topic.DLT`.
For each topic you created, example `XXX`, you need to create its corresponding `XXX.DLT` topic.

As a side-note, `ErrorHandlingDeserializer2` is *deprecated* since `2.5`.

**UPDATE:**
When you list topics `kafka-topics.bat --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092 --list`, are you able to see `test_topic.DLT`? And when you describe it `kafka-topics.bat --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092 --describe --topic test_topic.DLT`, can you see the same number of partitions as the original topic, more precisely can you see partition 2?

As per the [Spring Kafka Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#dead-letters):

> By default, the dead-letter record is sent to a topic named
> .DLT (the original topic name suffixed with .DLT) and
> to the same partition as the original record.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I created the topic DLT but it still doesn't work. Besides, `allow.auto.create.topics = true`

Comment: When you list topics `kafka-topics.bat --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092 --list`, are you able to see `test_topic.DLT`? And when you describe it `kafka-topics.bat --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092 --describe --topic test_topic.DLT`, can you see the same number of partitions as the original topic, more precisely can you see partition 2?

Comment: awesome question man. I ran the command and what I found is that the DLT topic only has 1 partition but the message is being pushed to the same partition number as that of the original topic. Meaning when a message comes from partition 4, it will also be pushed to the DLT topic at partition 4. This did not happen with previous versions. Maybe they changed the logic somewhere

Comment: Great, that was the reason of my question and why `allow.auto.create.topics = true` is not recommended i.e if you do not have a need to have topics created on the fly(although i am not sure if that is the cause of your issue, since your use case was successful in `v.2.2.7.RELEASE`). At least now, we know where lies the issue. As a side-note, i just replicated your issue on Spring Boot `v2.3.0.RELEASE`, with slightly different configuration than yours, and the record is being published correctly on my DLT, when i `throw new RuntimeException`. Strange.

Comment: I included a link to the report I submitted to Spring Kafka on github in my post. If you want you can download the zip file containing the test application. I could reproduce the issue consistently when I switch between the 2 versions. If you have time, maybe you can help me identify the differences with your test version and we both can learn why it worked for you in `v2.3.0.RELEASE`.

Comment: There is no difference between 2.5.x and earlier versions - the DLPR has always published to the same partition as the original message, by default. You can change that behavior by configuring a destination resolver. See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.5.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#dead-letters). `>Therefore, when you use the default resolver, the dead-letter topic must have at least as many partitions as the original topic.`